# how to import crossValidatorModel using sbt for scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependencies, sbt

i have a problem about CrossValidatorModel using scala sbt

this is my dependencies

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    // spark
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.1" % "provided" ,
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.1" % "provided",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.1" % "provided",

    // protobuf
    "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapbVersion % "protobuf",

    //for grpc
    "io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % grpcJavaVersion,
    "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime-grpc" % scalapbVersion
)
```

and this my code

but while i import CrossValidator, that give me an error like this
import org.apache.spark.ml.tuning.CrossValidatorModel

```
(grpc-default-executor-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/tuning/CrossValidatorModel$
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/ml/tuning/CrossValidatorModel$
        at MlModel$lr_model$.<init>(server.scala:28)
        at MlModel$lr_model$.<clinit>(server.scala)
        at HelloWorldServer$RouteGuideImpl.getLabel(server.scala:77)
```

i was tried using scala 2.11 and 2.12, spark 2.3.1, 2.1.0 but this gives me the same error.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve by changing this

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.1" % "provided",
```

to

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.3.1",
```